# How do I call one eclipse menu item after the click of another menu item?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am making use of eclipse to do web development. The activation of my code requires me to first **Save** my changes by clicking on one menu item and then clicking on another menu item called **Activate** so that the changes in saved file are pushed to the server.

I am looking for a way to call to the the Activate menu item once the save button is pressed, so that i can save a click.

Below is the flow I want to achieve.

*Make changes -> Press Save menu item -> This automatically calls the Activate Menu Item*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just execute a command, which is related to your Activate menu item:

```
// Obtain IServiceLocator implementer, e.g. from PlatformUI.getWorkbench():
IServiceLocator serviceLocator = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
// or a site from within a editor or view:
// IServiceLocator serviceLocator = getSite();

ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) serviceLocator.getService(ICommandService.class);

try  { 
    // Lookup commmand with its ID
    Command command = commandService.getCommand("org.eclipse.ui.help.helpContents");

    // Optionally pass a ExecutionEvent instance, default no-param arg creates blank event
    command.executeWithChecks(new ExecutionEvent());

} catch (ExecutionException | NotDefinedException |
        NotEnabledException | NotHandledException e) {

    // Replace with real-world exception handling
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```